# How to get keys associated to an index?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm using neo4j 1.9.9 and I'm trying to use a search using indexes (now called legacy indexes). However, I'm not sure about the key to use.

For example, because I have the `__types__` index created by `Spring Data neo4j`, I've done something like

```
start n=node:__types__(className="domain.Person") return n;
```

but it always returns 0 rows. I've also tried other kinds of keys instead of `className`, but nothing appears.

So, is there any way to know what keys are available for a given index?

Answer (score 1):

Use the Lucene Index Toolbox called [Luke](https://code.google.com/p/luke/) to get a low level access to the indexes located in `graph.db/index`. Please note that you cannot do this while Neo4j is running since the files get locked.

So either shut down Neo4j before using Luke or (preferred) take a copy of `graph.db/index` and use Luke on the copy.

Comment: Although it seems the best option until now, I still can't use it at all. I've tried 2 different versions and both fail to open every different kind of folder provided, don't know why.